# yii echo image not working on windows

Tags: yii

Hi I have the following code in Yii which works on linux apache, but on windows xampp it is giving an error:

```
    $aliasPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.upload');
    $imageUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish($aliasPath);
    echo CHtml::Image($imageUrl.'/logo.jpg','Client',array('width'=>'240'));`
```

it results in the following to be displayed in the browser:

```
getAssetManager()->publish($aliasPath); echo CHtml::Image($imageUrl.'/logo.jpg','Client',array('width'=>'240')); ?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is PHP definitely processing? And the php start tag intact (`<?php`)? If I use a .html file with this exact contents:

```
<?php 
$aliasPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.upload');
$imageUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish($aliasPath);
echo CHtml::Image($imageUrl.'/logo.jpg','Client',array('width'=>'240')); 

?>
```

Then I get exactly as you describe because it reads between the first `<` and the second `>` as a tag, and hides them as a completely unknown HTML tag.

You can test easily with a simple  page if PHP is processing at all

Comment: no dear the above code is a cut paste, so ?> instead of -> is not the case, thnks.